# Nested enums in Python

Tags: python, enums

I am trying to implement some kind of nested `Enum`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum


class VendorA(Enum):
    """Define price fields for VENDOR_A."""

    OPEN: str = "px_open"
    HIGH: str = "px_high"
    LOW: str = "px_low"
    CLOSE: str = "px_last"


class VendorB(Enum):
    """Define price fields for VENDOR_B."""

    OPEN: str = "open"
    HIGH: str = "high"
    LOW: str = "low"
    CLOSE: str = "close"


class DataVendor(Enum):
    """Define data vendor."""

    VENDOR_A: str = VendorA
    VENDOR_B: str = VendorB
```

I then define a new `Config` class.

```
@dataclass
class Config:
    """Configuration class."""

    data_vendor: DataVendor
```

After instatiating `Config`, I would like to directly access the nested price fields of the respective `data_vendor`.

However, using `Enum`, you can't directly access the price fields, i.e. the following code breaks with an error: `AttributeError: 'DataVendor' object has no attribute 'OPEN'`

```
conf = Config(data_vendor=DataVendor.VENDOR_A)

# I would like these assertions to pass.
assert conf.data_vendor.OPEN == "px_open"
assert conf.data_vendor.HIGH == "px_high"
assert conf.data_vendor.LOW == "px_low"
assert conf.data_vendor.CLOSE == "px_last"
```

If I were to use just regular classes (don't derive from `Enum`), the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: The Enum members have a name and a value. It looks like you want the value. This will pass `assert conf.data_vendor.value.OPEN.value == "px_open"`

Comment: @VPfB You're right. However, I am not sure if I would like to use it like this. The syntax feels somewhat clumsy.

Comment: If you focus on .attribue style acces and don't need symbolic names, enums are probably not a good choice, IMO. Vendors can be dataclasses. Or have a look at `types.SimpleNamespace`.

Comment: @Andi Use `class VendorA(str, Enum):` to create an enum. It will work the way you like.

Comment: @mx0 If I do that, ``conf.data_vendor`` has no attribute ``OPEN``.

Comment: @Andi this will allow comparison `OPEN == "px_open"`, you still need `VENDOR_A` part `conf.data_vendor.VENDOR_A.value.OPEN == "px_open"`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Enum` might not be the best idea in this case.

It works as desired by creating a class `Vendor` and defining class variables (`VENDOR1` and `VENDOR2`), whereby these variables hold the vendor specific information in a regular `dict`.

The actual initialization is then dependent on the `vendor_option` variable.

```
"""Module defines `Config` class."""
from typing import ClassVar


class Vendor:
    """Define vendors."""

    VENDOR1: ClassVar[dict] = {
        "name": "Vendor1",
        "open": "px_open",
        "high": "px_high",
        "low": "px_low",
        "close": "px_last",
    }
    VENDOR2: ClassVar[dict] = {
        "name": "Vendor2",
        "open": "open_price",
        "high": "high",
        "low": "low",
        "close": "close_price",
    }

    def __init__(self, vendor_option: str = "VENDOR1") -> None:
        """Set attributes according to vendor_option."""
        match vendor_option:
            case "VENDOR1":
                self.name = self.VENDOR1["name"]
                self.open_ = self.VENDOR1["open"]
                self.high = self.VENDOR1["high"]
                self.low = self.VENDOR1["low"]
                self.close = self.VENDOR1["close"]
            case "VENDOR2":
                self.name = self.VENDOR2["name"]
                self.open_ = self.VENDOR2["open"]
                self.high = self.VENDOR2["high"]
                self.low = self.VENDOR2["low"]
                self.close = self.VENDOR2["close"]
            case _:
                raise ValueError("Invalid vendor option")


class Config:
    """Define configuration."""

    def __init__(self, vendor: str = "VENDOR1") -> None:
        self.vendor = Vendor(vendor)


config = Config(vendor="VENDOR1")

print(config.vendor.close)  # prints "px_last"
```